# Upgrading Magento version 2.4.3 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

As Magento's new version 2.4.4 is about to release. all developers are looking for the upgrading process from **2.4.3 to 2.4.4**. what are the areas which we need to look into as developers?

what are the major changes happening? what if we are using third party applications and integrations in our Magento instance

Comment: Magento probably has a release notes document or webpage you can use for this. Requests for comparisons between two products or two versions of the same product are off-topic here as that is either an off-site resource or product recommendation, depending on how you phrase it. That being said, incremental patch updates should not be concerning as those should always be security patches or bug fixes that you **always** should be installing. Even minor updates (the second decimal) usually are no-brainer updates.

Answer (score 0):

The official upgrade guide can be found: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html